# Does Numpy fancy indexing copy values directly to another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

According to the documentation that I could find, when using fancy indexing a copy rather than a view is returned. However, I couldn't figure out what its behavior is during assignment to another array, for instance:

```
A = np.arange(0,10)
B = np.arange(-10,0)
fancy_slice = np.array([0,3,5])
A[fancy_slice] = B[fancy_slice]
```

I understand that `A` will just receive a call to `__setitem__` while `B` will get a call to `__getitem__`. What I am concerned about is whether an intermediate array is created before copying the values over to `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpreter will parse the code and issue the method calls as:

```
A[idx] = B[idx]

A.__setitem__(idx, B.__getitem__(idx))
```

The `B` method is evaluated fully before being passed to the `A` method.  `numpy` doesn't alter the Python interpreter or its syntax.  Rather it just adds functions, objects, and methods.

Functionally, it should be the equivalent to

```
temp = B[idx]
A[idx] = temp
del temp
```

We could do some `timeit` just be sure.

```
In [712]: A = np.zeros(10000,int)
In [713]: B = np.arange(10000)
In [714]: idx = np.arange(0,10000,100)
In [715]: timeit A[idx] = B[idx]
1.2 µs ± 3.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [716]: %%timeit
     ...: temp = B[idx]
     ...: A[idx] = temp
     ...: 
1.11 µs ± 0.669 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

There are some alternative functions/methods, like `add.at`, `copyto`, `place`, `put`, that may do some copies without an intermediate, but I haven't used them much.  This indexed assignment is good enough - most of the time.

Example with `copyto`

```
In [718]: wh = np.zeros(A.shape, bool)
In [719]: wh[idx] = True
In [721]: np.copyto(A, B, where=wh)
In [722]: timeit np.copyto(A, B, where=wh)
7.47 µs ± 9.92 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So even without timing the construction of the boolean mask, `copyto` is slower.

`put` and `take` are no better:

```
In [727]: timeit np.put(A,idx, np.take(B,idx))
7.98 µs ± 8.34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

An intermediate array is created. It *has* to be created. NumPy doesn't see

```
A[fancy_slice] = B[fancy_slice]
```

It sees

```
                 B[fancy_slice]
```

on its own, with no idea what the context is. This operation is defined to make a new array, and NumPy makes a new array.

*Then*, NumPy sees

```
A[fancy_slice] = <the array created by the previous operation>
```

and copies the data into `A`.